# Cantor's Diagonalization proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can diagonalization used to prove that set consisting of all finite subsets of the set, P are uncountable?

I am confused with this question.

Comment: What is the set $P$?

Comment: positive integers

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not a valid method.

First of all, this is not true, since the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is in fact countable. The second reason is that given a countable list of finite sets, the diagonalization argument *could* spit out an infinite set, which means that there is no contradiction.

For example, if you take $A_n=\{n+1\}$ as subsets of $\Bbb N$, then the diagonal argument will produce $\Bbb N$, which is indeed not one of the $A_n$'s, but it is not a finite set either.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The statement to be proved is not true in general.

Consider, for example, the set of natural numbers, $\mathbb N$. Denote the set of its finite subsets by $\mathscr N$. One can show that $\mathbb N$ and $\mathscr N$ are equivalent. That is, $\mathscr N$ is not uncountable.

For an $n\in \mathbb N$ there is an $N\in \mathscr N$. To see this, take the set of the powers in the prime decomposition of $n$. Now, take the sequence of primes, and an  $N\in\mathscr N$. Order the members of $N$ and use this ordered sequence as powers of the first few primes. The result is a member of $\mathbb N$.

The argumentation above can be repeated in the case of any countable sets. (They are equivalent to $\mathbb N$.)

If, however, a set is uncountable then the statement is trivial without any proof. In this case even the set containing only subsets of one element is already uncountable.

That is the diagonal method has nothing to do with the prrof of the OP's statement.

Comment: Your first sentence suffers from a scope ambiguity and makes it sound like the result is never true. But it is true for finite subsets of the reals, of course. What you mean is that the claim is not true for all sets, not that for all sets the claim is not true.

Comment: I edit accordingly...